# Get Location of DB instances the response from Node.JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have setup database cluster on MongoDB Atlas which consists of db instance from from EU, US, and Asia.
When connecting MongoDB Atlas using node.js, how to get the information of locations of db instance that response to my request?

Comment: `admindb.command( { hello: 1} ).then(conf => conf.primary)` will return your the hostname and port of the primary node. Unless you configured reads from secondaries, it's the node that responds to you.

Comment: @AlexBlex Thanks, I have a few read replicas, my purpose is to test whether it's reading from nearest replicas if possible, so just returning primary node is not sufficient

Comment: [explain().serverInfo](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/explain-results/#std-label-serverInfo) should show from where the data is read